# Difference between the format and db/format files in a Subversion repository

Tags: svn, svnserve

What is the difference between the following two files on an SVN server (ie not in a checked out repository)?

```
format
db/format
```

In our repositories the contents of the first is `5` while the contents of the second is `2`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The `format` file contains information about Subversion repository format, while `db/format` holds information about Subversion Repository **File System (FS)** format.

Repository format number:

- Formats 0, 1 and 2 were pre-1.0.
- Format 3 was current for 1.0 through
  to 1.3.
- Format 4 was an abortive
  experiment during the development of
  the locking feature in the lead up to
  1.2.
- Format 5 was new in 1.4, and is the first format which may contain BDB or FSFS filesystems with a FS format other than 1, since prior formats are accepted by some versions of Subversion which do not pay attention to the FS format number.

FSFS format number:

- Format 1, understood by Subversion 1.1+
- Format 2, understood by Subversion 1.4+, introduced support for [svn diff version 1](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.4#svndiff1)
- Format 3, understood by Subversion 1.5+, [sharded layout](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.5.html#fsfs-sharding) and storing [merge tracking information](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.5.html#merge-tracking)
- Format 4, understood by Subversion 1.6+, [represention sharing](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html#rep-sharing) and [repository packing](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.6.html#fsfs-packing)
- Format 5 was added during Subversion 1.7 development, but was removed [before 1.7.0 final release](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#revprop-packing)
- Format 6, understood by Subversion 1.8+, [revision properties packing](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#revprop-packing)
- Format 7, understood by Subversion 1.9+, [performance related changes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#fsfs-improvements)
- Format 8, understood by Subversion 1.10+, [LZ4 compression](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.10.html#lz4)

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any details about what the numbers mean? (I'm still going to accept your answer though, as you've answered my initial question)

Comment: I've updated my answer with brief description of different repository and FSFS versions.

Comment: And FSFS format 6 was added in Subversion 1.8.  It adds revprop packing as well as a few other improvements.  http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#fsfs-enhancements

Comment: @tgharold Thanks for reminder. I've added information about FSFS format 6 to my answer.

Comment: does someone know what Format 12 means ?

Comment: @ErdincAy Format 12 looks like Subversion **Working Copy** format, while this question about Subversion **Repository** formats. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364618 for information about Working Copy formats.