# subversion - how to tell the format of an existing repository

Tags: svn

Is there a way to tell the format of an svn repo on disk, without knowing how it was created? Possibly from the `format` or `db/format` files?

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/277441/difference-between-the-format-and-db-format-files-in-a-subversion-repository) has lots of useful info about the different contents of those files, but there's no answer to what backend format the repo is using.

The (gentoo) machine I'm on is running subversion 1.5.6:

```
me@foo ~ $ svn --version
svn, version 1.5.6 (r36142)
   compiled Jan 13 2010, 15:02:26
```

I created a couple of test repos to play with:

```
me@foo ~ $ svnadmin create --fs-type bdb bdb-repo
me@foo ~ $ svnadmin create --fs-type fsfs fsfs-repo
```

The `format` and `db/format` files look almost identical:

```
me@foo ~ $ more bdb-repo/format bdb-repo/db/format
::::::::::::::
bdb-repo/format
::::::::::::::
5
::::::::::::::
bdb-repo/db/format
::::::::::::::
3
me@foo ~ $ more fsfs-repo/format fsfs-repo/db/format
::::::::::::::
fsfs-repo/format
::::::::::::::
5
::::::::::::::
fsfs-repo/db/format
::::::::::::::
3
layout sharded 1000
```

The only difference being the `layout sharded 1000` line in the fsfs repo's `db/format` file. Is that the definitive indicator that it's using fsfs format? If not, is there some other way to tell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Discovered the answer. It's in the `db/fs-type` file.

```
me@foo ~ $ cat bdb-repo/db/fs-type 
bdb
me@foo ~ $ cat fsfs-repo/db/fs-type 
fsfs
```

[Reference here](http://www.svnforum.org/threads/38631-Need-to-know-if-my-SVN-Server-is-using-Berkeley-DB-or-FSFS?p=109670&viewfull=1#post109670).

I googled before I asked, I promise :)